# Differenze di uso tra "tenere", "conservare" e "mettere da parte"

Tags: word-usage, verbs, difference

So che il verbo inglese "to keep" si può tradurre come "tenere", "conservare" oppure "mettere da parte", ma non riesco a capire quali sono le differenze di uso tra questi tre verbi. Potreste spiegarmele?

Per esempio, immaginate che io prenda un foglio con dei compiti a uno studente perché non voglio che lo perda. Cosa dovrei dirgli?

> - Questo foglio lo *tengo* io perché non si perda.
> - Questo foglio lo *conservo* io perché non si perda.
> - Questo foglio lo *metto da parte* io perché non si perda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nel tuo esempio le prime due sono corrette (direi che la prima è quella che si userebbe comunemente, soprattutto nel parlato), la terza suona un po' strana.

"Mettere da parte" si usa tipicamente quando si parla di denaro, cibo o altre risorse che non si consumano immediatamente ma si conservano per un uso futuro. Normalmente suggerisce un processo graduale, in cui ciò che si mette da parte si accumula un po' alla volta.

> **Alcuni animali mettono da parte il cibo per l'inverno.**
>
> **I soldi che aveva messo da parte durante i suoi anni in America gli permisero di comprarsi la casa in cui viveva.**

C'è un proverbio che dice

> **Impara l'arte e mettila da parte.**

"Tenere" ha vari significati. Uno è quello del tuo esempio ("quedarse algo"):

> **Il libro puoi tener(te)lo, te lo regalo.**

Un altro è quello di "reggere" o "sorreggere" ("aguantar"):

> **Puoi salire, ti tengo io la scala.**

Spesso si usa col significato di "mantenere":

> **Mi tengo informato su ciò che accade.**
>
> **Sta tenendo un comportamento strano.**

Regionalmente si usa anche col significato di "avere":

> **Tengo famiglia.** (espressione, questa, ormai entrata nel linguaggio comune)

E anche nella lingua standard possono darsi contesti in cui i due concetti si sovrappongono:

> **Teneva in mano uno strano oggetto.**

Più molti altri significati (vedi ad es. [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tenere/))

"Conservare", infine, implica normalmente che si vuole impedire che ciò che si conserva venga usato, consumato o rovinato (in certo qual modo simile a "guardar", anche se non sempre):

> **Conserva ancora gelosamente il suo primo contratto.**

Un contesto tipico in cui si usa "conservare" è quando si parla di cibo. Su molte confezioni di cibo c'è scritto:

> **Conservare in frigorifero** (tra 0 e 4 gradi o similare).

Altro esempio:

> **Il freddo aiuta a conservare gli alimenti.**

Altri usi:

> **Ha perso tutto ma ha conservato il suo tipico senso dell'umorismo.**
>
> **In quel museo si trovano alcune opere molto ben conservate.**

Answer (score 2):

Tutte e tre le tue proposte vanno bene. Non saprei decidere quale sia la migliore, perché penso che tutte quante suonino perfettamente corrette e anche comuni. 
Così per intuizione da madrelingua ti consiglierei di usare la prima frase o la terza che hai proposto. Però ripeto, tutte e tre vanno bene secondo me. Magari in diverse zone d'Italia si sceglierebbe una piuttosto che l'altra.

In ogni caso, i tre verbi "tenere", "conservare" oppure "mettere da parte", possono nettamente essere usati come sinonimi. 
Tenere può indicare che tu tieni in mano qualcosa o che lo trattieni ( = metti da parte).

> 1) **TENERE** è il verbo dal significato più ampio e vario
>       Ho cercato di riassumere la lunga lista di connotazioni alle più comuni e usate.
>
> • Trattenere, afferrare qualcuno o qualcosa con le mani perché non sfugga o non cada o stia fermo (sinonimo reggere): *tieni la scala mentre salgo*.
>
> • Conservare qualcosa per un certo tempo: *t. una buona media di voti*.
>
> • Prendere, conservare per sé qualcosa: *può t. il resto*; in contesto noto. La cosa in se può essere sottintesa: *tieni!*
>
> • Contenere una certa quantità o un certo numero di oggetti o di persone: *lo stadio tiene centomila spettatori, l’aula tiene 30 studenti*.
>
> • Procedere secondo una stessa direzione (sinonimo mantenere) : *t. la destra*; anche in senso figurato seguire un certo modo di vivere, di agire, di comportarsi: *t. un contegno esemplare*.
>
> • Curare l'organizzazione di qualcosa, provvedere alla sua realizzazione: *t. una conferenza, un discorso*.
>
> • Mantenere qualcuno o qualcosa per un certo tempo in una determinata condizione o posizione: *t. un prigioniero; t. gli occhi bassi*.
>
> • Trattenere qualcosa in un certo posto, non lasciarlo andar via: *t. i bambini in casa; l'influenza mi tiene a letto*.
>
> • Mantenere, conservare qualcosa in un determinato posto: *t. le mani in tasca, un dolce al fresco*.
>
> • Conservare, occupare qualcosa per altri: *vai pure, ti tengo io il posto*.
>
> • (sinonimo di reggere): *il chiodo tiene*; fare presa: *una colla che non tiene*; detto di discorso, di ragionamento, essere valido, convincente: la tua ipotesi tiene.
>
> • Parteggiare per qualcuno o per qualcosa; nel l. sport, fare il tifo: *t. per l'Inter/ Milan ecc*.
>
> • Attribuire importanza, essere molto interessato a qualcuno o a qualcosa, anche nella forma tenerci: *t. molto a una persona; Giorgio ci tiene al denaro*.
>
> **Tenersi**
>
> • Sorreggersi, aggrapparsi a un appiglio per evitare di cadere: *t. a una corda*; in contesto noto l'argomento può essere sottinteso: *tenetevi forte!*
>
> • Trattenersi dal fare una cosa, con l'argomento espresso più spesso da un infinito in funzione di sostantivo: *non riusciva a t. dalle risa, dal ridere*.
>
> • Con valore di restare, mantenersi in una certa posizione, direzione, condizione (sinonimo rimanere, stare): *t. pronto*; (t. bene, su) o da un nome retto da una preposizione (*t. al corrente*).
>
> 2) **CONSERVARE** = Tenere con cura un oggetto o un bene; custodire, serbare.
>
> • Mantenere qualcuno preservare qualcosa da alterazioni: *c. i funghi sott'aceto*
>
> • Custodire, serbare qualcosa, spesso con specificazione del luogo: *c. i gioielli in cassaforte* || fig. *c. l'innocenza, l'onore*, non perderli.
>
> Esiste anche il verbo riflessivo **conservarsi**, che a mio parere è estremamente simile in significato e uso a tenersi. Ecco degli esempi:
>
> • Detto di cose, restare immune da alterazioni; detto di persone, rimanere in buona salute
>
> • Con valore di permanere in un certo stato: *c. onesto;* il compl. predicativo può essere espresso anche da un avverbio (*c. male*) o da un nome retto da prep. (*c. in buona salute)*.
>
> 3)  **METTERE DA PARTE** è di uso più colloquiale e significa:
>
> • riporre in un luogo (da parte, via) *Metti via i giochi e vieni a tavola.*
>
> • mettere da parte come riserva *mettere via i soldi per comprare la casa*.